# Plot a categorical variable below or above the X axis on a plot that has secondary Y axis

Tags: python, plotly

Context: I have a dataframe and I'm plotting a line plot and a bar plot on the same chart. Now, I'd like to add a type of "timeline" below the date on the main X axis or above the chart as a secondary x axis.

Minimal reproducible code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import base64
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

plot_df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['2022-01-01','2022-01-02','2022-01-03','2022-01-04','2022-01-05'],'A':[2.1,2.4,3.2,4.2,2.4],'B':[12,23,24,27,17],'C':[np.nan,500,200,np.nan,np.nan],'D':['pre','during','during','post','post']})
plot_df


fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Line(x=plot_df['time'], y=plot_df['A'],name='A'),secondary_y=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Line(x=plot_df['time'], y=plot_df['B'],name='B'),secondary_y=True)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=plot_df['time'], y=plot_df['C'],name='C'), secondary_y=False)

fig.update_layout(
    #margin=dict(l=2, r=1, t=55, b=2),
    autosize=True,
    xaxis=dict(title_text="Time"),
    yaxis=dict(title_text="C"),
    width=1000
    )

fig.show()
```

From this, I get this plot:
(I'm actually getting an error for now uploading the image, I'll update the post with the plot as soon as I can)

Image: (uploaded using ImgBB) https://ibb.co/w6w8677

The idea would essentially to take the column `D` and plot the "pre","during" and "post" on top of the plot or right below the "time" on the x axis (whichever would be easier/more visually appealing)

How could I do that?

Ultimate goal for the output would be something like this (doesn't have to have the same box size or fonts or colors, just an example of how to do something like this):

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Why didn't you add it as a subpot?

Comment: Add it as subplot? How come? The goal would be to add the bars/labels (pre, during, post) on below the X axis or on top of the graph. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: Never mind, I understood you right now.

Comment: Does this link help? https://community.plotly.com/t/can-plotly-support-2-x-axis-and-2-y-axis-in-one-graph/38303/2

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried the method described by the plotly community, but I think it is less time consuming to select a string annotation than to add a second axis with no data. The method I have taken is not to use a time series, but to combine the date string and D column values as labels for the x-axis scale.
The other method is to use a string annotation at the top of the graph. Which one you choose is up to you.

```
plot_df
    time    A   B   C   D
0   2022-01-01  2.1     12  NaN     pre
1   2022-01-02  2.4     23  500.0   during
2   2022-01-03  3.2     24  200.0   during
3   2022-01-04  4.2     27  NaN     post
4   2022-01-05  2.4     17  NaN     post

plot_df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   time    5 non-null      object 
 1   A       5 non-null      float64
 2   B       5 non-null      int64  
 3   C       2 non-null      float64
 4   D       5 non-null      object 
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 328.0+ bytes

import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np

xlabels = ['{}</br></br>{}'.format(t,d) for t,d in zip(plot_df['time'], plot_df['D'])]

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='lines', x=plot_df.index, y=plot_df['A'], name='A'), secondary_y=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='lines', x=plot_df.index, y=plot_df['B'], name='B'), secondary_y=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=plot_df.index, y=plot_df['C'], name='C'), secondary_y=False)

for i,d in enumerate(plot_df['D']):
    fig.add_annotation(x=i, y=1.1, xref='x', yref='paper', text=d, showarrow=False)

fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=np.arange(5), ticktext=xlabels)

fig.update_layout(
    #margin=dict(l=2, r=1, t=55, b=2),
    autosize=True,
    xaxis=dict(title_text="Time"),
    yaxis=dict(title_text="C"),
    width=1000
    )

fig.show()
```

[image]

Update: Case example of manually adding a string annotation as the expected output is updated.

```
fig.add_annotation(x=0, y=1.1, xref='paper', yref='paper', text='             Pre             ', showarrow=False, font=dict(color='white'), bgcolor='blue')
fig.add_annotation(x=0.31, y=1.1, xref='paper', yref='paper', text='            During            ', showarrow=False, font=dict(color='blue'), bgcolor='gray')
fig.add_annotation(x=0.94, y=1.1, xref='paper', yref='paper', text='            Post            ', showarrow=False, font=dict(color='blue'), bgcolor='green')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input! On my graph however I'm now seeing this: https://ibb.co/613xkqH

Comment: I am reading and using the data you have presented. We share the data we read and the information in the data frame. Perhaps the time column is in datetime format? Try converting it to a string.

Comment: When I do that I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'` -> `plot_df['time'] = plot_df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`

Comment: Was the data type of the data frame the same? The error may be due to the fact that you have already added a string and converted it to a date/time string.

Comment: The point of my response is not to use time series data, but to use data frame indexes. `fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='lines', x=plot_df.index,...)`

Comment: The expected output has been updated and the code and graphs have been added accordingly. I have added a background color to the string to annotate it, but added whitespace to make the background wider. There may be more efficient ways to do it other than this, but you can modify the rest yourself.

Comment: Hey thank you for the updated input! This would need to be dynamic however since plotly allows the user to drag the dates to a window of his/her choosing and adding notation with spaces won't adjust automatically. I'll try using the secondary axis of plotly, but thank you! :)